# Using RStudio and Knitr, how to color-code a specific column variadically?

Tags: r, rstudio, knitr, variadic-templates, variadic

I have a dataframe `df` built from `base::colors(TRUE);` that can be seen as a sample below:

```
df = structure(list(color = c("white", "aliceblue", "antiquewhite", 
"antiquewhite1", "antiquewhite2", "antiquewhite3", "antiquewhite4", 
"aquamarine", "aquamarine2", "aquamarine3", "aquamarine4", "azure", 
"azure2", "azure3", "azure4", "beige", "bisque", "bisque2", "bisque3", 
"bisque4"), hex.color = c("#FFFFFF", "#F0F8FF", "#FAEBD7", "#FFEFDB", 
"#EEDFCC", "#CDC0B0", "#8B8378", "#7FFFD4", "#76EEC6", "#66CDAA", 
"#458B74", "#F0FFFF", "#E0EEEE", "#C1CDCD", "#838B8B", "#F5F5DC", 
"#FFE4C4", "#EED5B7", "#CDB79E", "#8B7D6B"), r = c(255, 240, 
250, 255, 238, 205, 139, 127, 118, 102, 69, 240, 224, 193, 131, 
245, 255, 238, 205, 139), g = c(255, 248, 235, 239, 223, 192, 
131, 255, 238, 205, 139, 255, 238, 205, 139, 245, 228, 213, 183, 
125), b = c(255, 255, 215, 219, 204, 176, 120, 212, 198, 170, 
116, 255, 238, 205, 139, 220, 196, 183, 158, 107)), row.names = c(NA, 
20L), class = "data.frame")
```

You can see how it renders:

[image]

#### I would like to have it render based on the column of the dataframe `df$hex.color`.

Ideally, it would maybe be a new column `df$empty` that I can fill with the color.  So people can see the "name", the "hex val", and visually see the color without me having to put it in a large graphic.

Using RStudio, Knitr, how to color-code a specific column variadically?

Answer (score 0):

This might be one approach using `kableExtra`. I tried this out in an RMarkdown document with HTML rendering. This involves creating a new column `empty` that contains blank spaces. Using `cell_spec` from `kableExtra` you can indicate the background color of cells in the `empty` column, based on `hex.color`. Make sure to include `escape = FALSE` for your blank spaces.

```
library(kableExtra)
library(dplyr)

df$empty = strrep("&nbsp;", 10)

df %>%
  mutate(empty = cell_spec(empty, background = hex.color, escape = FALSE)) %>%
  kable(escape = FALSE) %>%
  kable_styling()
```

Comment: Looks like a start, thank you.  I would prefer a non `Perl` solution (I had to learn perl for work back in the late 1990s).  I don't need new grammar; I got enough going on trying to figure out the `base` grammar and its quirks.  Getting R to follow C-grammar is all I want.  I looked into piping ... I guess it is an attempt to bring ECMA to R?

Comment: I tried "it" out last semester using `rvest` ... after rewriting the piped code using my traditionalist mindset (in about 1/3 the time), I didn't see any upside of "right-side" stacking functions over the left-side stacking:  ```hexdec( dechex( hexdec("CC") ) );``` or ```dechex( hexdec( dechex( hexdec("CC") ) ) );```  Will `kable_styling(kable(df, escape=FALSE))` work?  I think I can figure out the `mutate` workaround.

Comment: `cell_spec` seems to call `cell_spec_html` which I believe is a private function in the package.  I need to review more.  Most of these packages are just rendering html by adding an attribute.  If I have an html str, it won't render in a notebook, unless `castStringAsHTML(str);` which is what most of these libraries are doing under the hood.

Comment: Not much too it:  ```castStringAsHTML = function(str)
 {
 str = setAttribute("html", TRUE, str);

 class(str) = c("html", "character");
 str;
 }``` which is referencing another of my "application-level" getter-setter functions: ```setAttribute = function(myAttribute, myValue, myObj)
 {
 attributes(myObj)[[myAttribute]] = myValue; 
 myObj;  # no object referencing, so I must return
 }```

Comment: Run `castStringAsHTML(str);` in a R chunk and it will render and knit.